# ZEND zf2 trying to debug controller not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am getting a 404 for controller not found and I am having difficulty debugging it.

Where would I debug in Zend zf2 to see what controller it is actually looking for?

The error is:

A 404 error occurred
Page not found.

The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
    not-found(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: not-found)

No Exception available

So my question is not for you to find my problem but to help m3 find where in ZEND I can put breakpoints - help me learn to debug what ZEND is doing.

Between the service manager and listeners and autoloaders, and factories etc... I find ZEND so complex that I can't figure out where to put a breakpoint and see what is happening - in this case what controller is it trying to open.

"Teach a man to fish, rather than feed the man fish".

Thanks

Comment: The error message should include this. Please edit your question to include the full error message you are receiving if it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

For that problem i don't think you can use breakpoint. Because it gives error before action starts, it couldn't found the controller.

My solution for that when i face with that problem.

1. Check controller file if it has the correct name in both file and class definition and namespace.
2. Check module.config file for routing and controller definition.
3. If you are not using autoloader, check classmap file.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I could not find a breakpoint location. I found my problem in that I spelled "default" without the plural "defaults". Nevertheless, I did not achieve my goal of finding the problem through tracing the code.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your routes you are using a controller which is not defined under the 'controllers' key in your module.config.php

For example in this route there is a controller 'Application\Controller\Index':

```
'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

And you have to create a controller entry:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
    ),
),
```

Comment: I did that, so there is a problem somewhere else. I am trying to figure out where to put a breakpoint to see what controller it is really attempting to load, and I can'f figure it out. if  your step through from the beginning there are a million steps

Comment: can you please update your question with the ful error message?